# Advantage over using inner or nested class in AsynTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, swingworker

Whether in Android or Java, when we call an `AsyncTask` or `SwingWorker` it can be used a inner or nested class. I'm concerned about memory leak issues most in Android devices. If you take an inner class the activity reference it's automatically passed. By taking a nested class you'll have to manually pass the activity reference so inner/nested are basically doing the same work.

One problem I've had is that the activity dies and when the `AsyncTask` ends it will broke the app. I know and have used headless fragments, but here my question is about using inner/nested classes in both Android and Java, which one do you recommend? For example, I perform this task in `JFrame`, of course I want to use a specific class that does the particular task (one class for each task) instead of placing inline code.

```
new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        private Exception exception = null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            try {
                callback.login();
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                exception = e;
            }

            return null;                
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            if(exception != null) {
                // show fail
            } else {
                update();
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a class as inner class if the class has no identity without parent class and mark the inner class as static to avoid the issues that you have mentioned.

In Android you can pass the [Weak reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) of parent Activity to avoid leaks and ensure that AsyncTask is cancelled in `onStop`. Generally try to avoid usage AsyncTask as much as possible. Use it for trivial usecases. For major use-cases, rely on Services/IntentService.

From programmer's point of view its quite convenient to just create a inner class and let the class access the parent class's data. But it causes some workload on compiler. Internally compiler generates getter methods and adds it your code before generating .class files. This is not a great idea since it impacts the encapsulation of the parent class

Answer (score 0):

In Android, you can handle this situation with the implementation of `interface`. Let us have an `interface` like the following.

```
public interface HttpResponseListener {
    void httpResponseReceiver(String result);
}
```

Now from your `Activity` while calling the login function through an `AsyncTask`, just the pass the interface from the activity class to the `AsyncTask`. Remember that your `AsyncTask` should have an instance variable of that listener as well. So the overall implementation should look like the following.

```
public abstract class HttpRequestAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    public HttpResponseListener mHttpResponseListener;
    private final Context mContext;

    HttpRequestAsyncTask(Context mContext, HttpResponseListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mHttpResponseListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result = null;

        try {
            result = login(mContext); // use the context if necessary
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
        mHttpResponseListener.httpResponseReceiver(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mHttpResponseListener.httpResponseReceiver(null);
    }
}
```

Now you need to have the `httpResponseReceiver` function implemented in the calling `Activity`. So the sample activity should look like.

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HttpResponseListener {
    // ... Other code and overriden functions 

    public void callAsyncTaskForLogin() {
        // Pass the listener here
        HttpRequestAsyncTask loginTask = new HttpRequestGetAsyncTask(
            YourActivity.this, this);
            loginTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    @Override
    public void httpResponseReceiver(String result) {
        // Get the response callback here
        // Do your changes in UI elements here. 
    }
}
```

This is how you can avoid the potential memory leak, as you are changing the UI elements using the context of the activity inside your activity. When the background `AsyncTask` finishes, it passes the responsibility to the callback function and does not hold the reference of the context.

In case of finishing of the application, the `AsyncTask` will execute and will pass the reference to the calling activity and in that case, the activity will not be available to receive. However, this will not generate any memory leak either.